# Pick out object from array using id. Node.js and Express

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have a task from school, and we are working with Node.js & Express. Now im stuck.

If i paste this into my browser *http://localhost:3000/courses/2* i need to get the course with ID of 2 in the array below. Thist is part of the array...

```
courses[0] = '{"_id":1,"courseId":"DT162G","courseName":"Javascript-baserad webbutveckling","coursePeriod":1}';
courses[1] = '{"_id":2,"courseId":"IK060G","courseName":"Projektledning","coursePeriod":1}';
courses[2] = '{"_id":3,"courseId":"DT071G","courseName":"Programmering i C#.NET","coursePeriod":2}';
courses[3] = '{"_id":4,"courseId":"DT148G","courseName":"Webbutveckling för mobila enheter","coursePeriod":2}';
```

Here is my code

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {

    var id = req.params.id;
    var get_course = "No course found!";


        for(row of courses){
            course_id = row;
            // MY PROBLEM IS HERE
            if(course_id.indexOf(id) > 0) get_course = row;
            //
        }

    console.log(get_course);
    res.contentType('application/json');
    res.send(get_course);
})
```

My problem is in the for loop, we hade instructions to try to pick it out with indexOf(), not necessary though. But i cant get it to work. I have tried alot here, so the solution above i know is not working.

With that solution im getting the course with id of 6, because of the indexOf, so thats not right but u guys can see the problem i hope.

Comment: what do u mean by ID of 2, are you referring to _id in the object or array index

Comment: and you are storing the object as strings in the array

Comment: Oh sorry, if im in the browser  writing localhost:3000/2 in the adress field, then i need "_id":2,"courseId":"IK060G"..  to be displayed

Answer (score 0):

First of all check that you have an array of strings.

You can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array of Objects from `courses` by calling `JSON.parse(i)` over all the items.

Then you can use [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to return the first element in
   the array that satisfies the provided testing function:

```js
var courses = ['{"_id":1,"courseId":"DT162G","courseName":"Javascript-baserad webbutveckling","coursePeriod":1}','{"_id":2,"courseId":"IK060G","courseName":"Projektledning","coursePeriod":1}','{"_id":3,"courseId":"DT071G","courseName":"Programmering i C#.NET","coursePeriod":2}','{"_id":4,"courseId":"DT148G","courseName":"Webbutveckling för mobila enheter","coursePeriod":2}'],
    id = 2,
    course = courses.map((i) => JSON.parse(i)).find((c) => c._id === id);

console.log(course);
```

Note that `id = 2` is the request param id.

Comment: My bad, its not an object. Its stored as a string

Comment: Check the update answer. First map all the courses to create a new array of Objects and then find the course with `id === 2`